# simple java hadoop programe (counting average score) didn't work

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to change a counting average score hadoop programe to a programe that can output all the score as well as average score and total score. Before I modified the program, it can output the average score correctly in Eclipse. But after I modified it, it didn't get an output. Because I am new to Hadoop and Java, I have compared my programe with many workable programe, but I cannot find out what happend.

The workable Reduce:

```
 public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{
     public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        Iterator<IntWritable> iterator = values.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            sum += iterator.next().get();
            count++;
        }
        int average = (int) sum / count;
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(average));
    }
}
```

The modified Reduce:

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text>{
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        String scoreList = new String();
        Iterator<IntWritable> iterator = values.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            int score = iterator.next().get();
            sum += score;
            count++;
            scoreList += String.format(" %d", score);
        }
        int average = (int) sum / count;
        scoreList += String.format(" %d", average);
        scoreList += String.format(" %d", sum);
        context.write(key, new Text(scoreList));
    }
}
```

And the modified main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:9000");
    String[] ioArgs = new String[] {"score_in", "score_out2"};
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, ioArgs).getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: Score <input> <output>");
        System.exit(2);
    }

    String inputDirName = otherArgs[0];
    String outputDirName = otherArgs[1];
    Job job = new Job(conf, "Score2");
    job.setJarByClass(Score2.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputDirName));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputDirName));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Could someone help me to make my programe work? Thank you very much!

Comment: What does "args" output when you try to print them out ? Also I am not sure if you have to use GenericOptionsParser with respect to your code.

Comment: I have added `System.out.println(inputDirName);`, but it didn't get any output.

Comment: What is the ouput of System.out.println for "args" array ?

Comment: It seem no ouput of System.out.println for "args" array

Comment: How about the value of args before this line "args = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();" ? Is that empty as well.

Comment: Sorry for my wrong question! I think my problem is when I change the value type of reduce (IntWritable -> Text), I cannot get any output, because the programe can run in Eclipse, and build a folder for output, it just doesn't have a output. I have tried another example, and when I change the value type, it didn't get an ouput again.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood what you want to say. Could you post the "reduce" signature that works and that does not. It may help.

Comment: I have edited the problem description, and post the "reduce" signature.